# Kdialog unable to cancel job with ffmpeg from progressbar , with other command it works :S

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

i did a script to convert my stuff with ffmpeg

it does :

1 create  progressbar with cancel button 
2 loop to convert files 
3 set the progress value

it works fine but it doens't stop ffmpeg when i click on cancel

the strange thing is that when i use another program like  echo it works like it should it seems a ffmpeg issue

can onyone help me how to find out the trick ?

```
listoffile="$HOME/ffmpeglist.lst"
numberoffile=$(wc -l <$listoffile)
ffmpegpath="/usr/bin/ffmpeg"

    mystufvariabletouseonmyscript=$(kdialog --progressbar "hello this is a progress bar with 100 steps" 100) ;  sleep 2 ; qdbus $mystufvariabletouseonmyscript  showCancelButton true




    until test "true" = `qdbus  $mystufvariabletouseonmyscript wasCancelled` ; do 

            while read line ; do
                qdbus $mystufvariabletouseonmyscript org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.setLabelText $"Starting Conversion...processing file $line"


                $ffmpegpath -i   "$line"   "${line%%.*}.$mp3" 


                value=$(( $(($a*100))/$numberoffile ))
                qdbus  $mystufvariabletouseonmyscript Set org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog value $value
                a=$(($a+1))

                done< "$listoffile"

        done
```

Comment: Seems like you are only checking for cancellation in-between runs of FFmpeg. Do you want to able to abort it while it’s still running?

Comment: well i would like kill ffmpeg and the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my answer make sure you have set a folder i did for this one

/usr/share/sounds/  but it's a good example because files are very short so...

```
ls -d -1 /usr/share/sounds/*.* > /tmp/listoffile.txt 
a=$(kdialog --title $"FFmpeg Dolphin Service Menu"  --progressbar $"Starting Conversion..." 100)
b=$(kdialog --title $"FFmpeg Dolphin Service Menu"  --progressbar $"Global work..." 100)

qdbus $b  showCancelButton true

qdbus $b org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.autoClose true


numberoffile=$(wc -l <"/tmp/listoffile.txt")
echo $numberoffile
count=1

while  read <&3 line ; do 

    while read linetwo ; do
qdbus $a org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.setLabelText $"Processing file..... $line"
        qdbus $a  showCancelButton true
        while [[  $(qdbus  $a wasCancelled) != "false" || $(qdbus  $b wasCancelled) != "false"  ]] ; do
            echo -e "$COL_RED ECHO KILLING AXEL AND KDIALOG $COL_RESET"
            qdbus $a  org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.close 
            qdbus $b  org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog.close 
            exit
        done

        qdbus  $a Set org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog value  "$linetwo"

    done < <((pv -W -n "$line" | ffmpeg -y ciao.flac -i pipe:0 2>/tmp/logffm.lst) 2>&1 )
    v=$(( $(($count*100))/$numberoffile ))
    echo $(($count*100)) and 
    count=$(($count+1))
    echo "qdbus  $b Set org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog value $v"
    qdbus  $b Set org.kde.kdialog.ProgressDialog value $v

done 3<"/tmp/listoffile.txt"
```